Subsetting a string with the degree symbol in it
I am trying to split this latitude into its component degrees minutes and seconds to then convert into decimal for further processing
57°46'52"W
by using .indexOf("°") which returns -1, meaning the degree symbol is not found.
I have also tried .indexOf("\u00b0") which also returns -1 and I had a similar lack of success when using .replace("°","") on another value which did not remove the degree symbol.
How do I find the position of the degree symbol ° so I can pull the preceding digits? The degrees can vary from one to three digits, so I must be able to find the degree symbol.

Try "57°46'52\"W".split("\\D")

Which symbol/character does your input string contain?

A [MCVE] would improve this Question.

Now that you’ve confirmed that the text is read from an ISO 8859-1 file, please edit your question and show the code which reads from that file.  Using the wrong (possibly implicit) charset would explain the problem you’re having.

As you can see in this online compiler snippet, there is nothing wrong with "57°46'52\"W".indexOf("°") - it returns 2 as you'd expect. Your problem  may be due to one of these causes:

Wrong source encoding in your Java source file. In this case, using \u00b0 should fix it.
Reading your input using the wrong encoding. Make sure you use the right charset when creating a Reader from an InputStream (or whatever means you use to get your input).
The input has already been corrupted after going through a bad encoding, even before reaching your application. In this case, check your input by printing the hex codes of your characters, to check how it is stored in your String. If it is incorrect, try to debug the source of your input.
The input does not contain a Unicode U+00B0 degree symbol, but instead it's one of the various symbols that look like it. Check your input by printing the hex codes.


Problem is No 2 above.

The encoding of the file is StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1

You could also do it like this.

split on the symbols
filter on the values to pass just the numerics
convert to an int and store in an array

String lat = "57°46'52\"W";
int[] dms = Arrays.stream(lat.split("[°'\"]"))
         .filter(str -> str.matches("\\d+"))
         .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
         .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dms));

prints
[57, 46, 52]


import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String inStr = "57°46'52\"W";

    String ptn_part1 = "^([0-9]{1,3})[^0-9]{1}";
    String ptn_part2 = "([0-9]{1,3})[^0-9]{1}";
    String ptn_part3 = "([0-9]{1,3})[^0-9]{1,4}";
    String ptnStr = ptn_part1+ptn_part2+ptn_part3;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ptnStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inStr);

    System.out.println("Result = " + matcher.find());
    System.out.println("Result = " + matcher.group(1)); // 57
    System.out.println("Result = " + matcher.group(2)); // 46
    System.out.println("Result = " + matcher.group(3)); // 52
  }
}


be aware that given regular expression will also find a date/time like "24-09-02T10:30:00"
